# Create and Pass a Table-Valued Parameter in a Single Line

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

Using SQL Server 2012, is it possible to eliminate the need to declare a table-valued parameter (TVP) just to pass it into a stored procedure?  Below is a really simple example of a stored procedure (SP) that takes a TVP and a working example to execute that SP where I have to declare the TVP, populate it and then pass it into the SP.  I would like to be able to simply pass in the population criteria directly to the EXEC call.  Is this possible?

**Scenario Setup:**

```
-- Create a sample Users table
CREATE TABLE Users (UserID int, UserName varchar(20))
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (1, 'Bob'), (2, 'Mary'), (3, 'John'), (4, 'Mark')

-- Create a TVP Type
CREATE TYPE UserIdTableType AS TABLE (UserID int)

-- Create SP That Uses TVP Type
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUsers
@UserIdFilter UserIdTableType READONLY
AS
    SELECT * FROM @UserIdFilter WHERE UserID > 2
```

**Working Method to Execute:**

```
DECLARE @MyIds AS UserIdTableType
INSERT INTO @MyIds SELECT UserID FROM Users
EXEC GetUsers @MyIds
```

**Requested Method to Execute:**

```
EXEC GetUsers (SELECT UserID FROM Users)
```

Comment: It is a TVP that procedure is expecting not a select query, You will need to declare a TVP specifically of a type that this procedure accepts , populate it and then pass it to the proc , you cannot simple just pass a select query instead of the TVP.

Comment: @M.All, is there any way to cast it as a TVP in a single line?  Something like `EXEC GetUsers CAST((SELECT UserID FROM Users) as UserIdTableType)`?  I'm just looking for a shortcut way to make the calling code look cleaner.

Comment: nope you cannot but you can pass your query as it is , as a parameter and execute it inside your proc, you will need to use dynamic sql for that.

Comment: Yea, that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @bigmac Just curious if you had a chance to try this out. It does avoid dynamic SQL :-).

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot create a TVP inline or CAST / CONVERT it. It is not a "Data Type" like `INT`, `VARCHAR`, `DATETIME`, etc.; it is a "Table Type" which is entirely different. The User-Defined Table Type (UDTT) is just meta-data that is used as the definition/schema for the declaration of a Table Variable. When such a Table Variable is used as an input parameter, that usage is considered a TVP (Table-Valued Parameter). But the thing is still a Table Variable which has its definition stored in `tempdb`. This is a physical structure, not a memory structure, and you can't `CAST` or `CONVERT` a Table, whether it is real, temporary, or a variable.

While the example given in the Question is simplistic for the sake of just getting the idea across, it does seem like your overall goal is code-reuse / creating subroutines (else you could have easily done `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID > 2`). Unfortunately T-SQL doesn't allow for really elegant / clean code, so you will have to accept a certain level of repetition and/or clunkiness.

It is possible, however, to make slightly generic handlers for result sets, provided they at least have the required fields. You could either

- pass in an XML parameter, or
- dump the results to a temp table and just refer to it in the sub-proc call (doesn't need to be dynamic SQL) and hence no need to pass in any parameter (at least not one for the dataset / results / query)

In both of those cases, the structure is more flexible than using a TVP since the TVP has to be those exact fields. But referencing a temp table that is assumed to exist allows for something similar to the following:

**Proc_1**

```
SELECT *
INTO #MyTemp
FROM sys.tables;

EXEC dbo.Proc_4 @StartsWith = 'a', @HowMany = 10;
```

**Proc_2**

```
SELECT *
INTO #MyTemp
FROM sys.columns;

EXEC dbo.Proc_4 @StartsWith = 'bb', @HowMany = 20;
```

**Proc_3**

```
SELECT *
INTO #MyTemp
FROM sys.views;

EXEC dbo.Proc_4 @StartsWith = 'ccc', @HowMany = 33;
```

**Proc_4**

```
SELECT TOP (@HowMany) tmp.*
FROM   #MyTemp tmp
WHERE  tmp.[name] LIKE @StartsWith + '%'
ORDER BY tmp.[object_id] ASC;
```

Comment: Is the "dump the results to a temp table and just refer to it in the sub-proc" approach thread-safe?

Comment: @JonSchneider I don't see how it couldn't be. A local temp table is local to the Session it is created in. Even with connection pooling keeping that same Session, the first action upon coming back to that Session is to run an internal stored procedure that wipes out any prior local temp tables. Also, I have worked on systems with hundreds to thousands of transactions per second, doing stuff like this (though not terribly frequently), and all was fine.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure how/whether SQL Server shared temp tables between sessions.

Comment: @JonSchneider Yer welcome. And a whole mess of stuff would break if sessions, even re-used connections from a pool on the same Session ID, shared local temp tables. And there is no ability for them to be shared between session since if you look at `tempdb.sys.tables` you will see that each local temp table name has a hash code appended to it, providing that separation.

Comment: Note that this approach will recompile the query in the inner Proc_4 for each execution of the outer proc (1/2/3). See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2007/01/18/11-0-temporary-tables-table-variables-and-recompiles/) (scroll to "Now consider a case when the temporary table is referenced in a second stored procedure as below:"). And when you turn back to TVPs with their verbosity, keep in mind that they [don't carry statistics and are subject to "parameter sniffing"](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/03/table-valued-parameters-unexpected-parameter-sniffing/)..